# How can you make a new Storyboard View Appear Without a Button

Tags: ios

I am creating a game that ends when the timer is up and a new end game view appears I have not been able to get the view to switch to the next view in the story board when time expires, all that appears is a black screen. This is the code where it switches view controllers

```
- (void)subtractTime {
    // 1
    seconds--;
    timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %i",seconds];

    // 2
    if (seconds == 0) {
        [timer invalidate];
        GamerOverViewController *gamerOverViewController = [[GamerOverViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:gamerOverViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

and this is the code in the new view controller where I am trying to make a view with a label appear:

```
- (IBAction)goNext:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushTo10" sender:self];
}
```

Thanks for any help in getting this to work.

Comment: Use segues or don't.  Please don't half-and-half it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to present a view using `presentViewController:animated:completion:`, you must `initWithNibName:` rather than just `init`.  The `viewController` you're presenting has to know what nib to load (and then control) when it's pushed.

Better is to just use segues.

```
if(seconds==0) {
    [timer invalidate];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"whateverYourSegueIsNamed" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: When I use this method as soon as the timer expires the app crashes with "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" and flashes to main.m with a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error.

Comment: @user1828081 You need to replace "whateverYourSegueIsNamed" with what your segue is actually named on the storyboard.  You haven't provided enough information for me to actually diagnose the exception, however, it's almost certainly saying something about "No segue exists with identifier..."

Answer (score 1):

Try use `[[UIStoryBoard stroyBoardWithName:@"MainStoryboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GamerOverViewController"]` to instantiate the `GamerOverViewController` instead of using `alloc init`. Remember you have to set the identifier in storyboard